# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error while trying to access url using typescript and angular2

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am trying to retrieve a service which is running on another port.I am getting an error as follows

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

my service.ts file is as follows

```
getDeviceInfo(){
   let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000',);
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Authorization')
    let options = new RequestOptions({
      method: RequestMethod.Get,
      url: DEVICE_URL,
      headers: headers
    });
    return  this.http.request(new Request(options))
      .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Those headers should be set in server side not client app.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: is there any alternative to set them at the client side?

Comment: nope.. you should set your server side CORS

Comment: For development purpose you can disable CORS in crome browser. But please make sure this is for development purpose and permanent solution is to set CORS at server side.
Please refer the below link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per browser policy *CORS* is not allowed. Howerver if you are using chrome extension **POSTMAN** or app such as **INSOMINA**  *cors* error wont occur.

**How to pass cors error?**

> CORS error should only pass by server side.

Consider if your are using *express* as your server side. Then add following middleware in you app route.

```
  app.use(function(req,res){
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Header' , 'authorization');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't. Try Oauth to get information/data from other websites.

Comment: What do you mean by _You simply can't_ and how is this related to OAuth? This is just CORS issue which could be solved by setting required headers in the response headers